# How to add server side filter/rule in emails when requested by user in Android?

Tags: android, imap, email-client

I am working on an Android Email Application but have no idea how to put server side filter/rule on user request. The rule shall be defined by the user of the app.

Adding server side rules is necessary so that when user opens his account in Thunderbird/Outlook or web, he can get same kind of emails flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Server side filtering is entirely dependent on the facilities provided by the particular mail server; it is not part of the IMAP protocol.

While some ISPs may publish an interface for programmatically editing server side filter rules, you can't hope to provide a single client-side implementation of this in your Android app which will work across the board.

Answer (score 1):

One fo the protocols used to manage server-side filters is ManageSieve for Sieve filters.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5804
Popular Dovecot IMAP server has ManageSieve support.